# Access different fields on 'ManyRelatedManager' using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to access fields on the through table of my ManyToMany link to serialize into a JSON via Django Rest Frameworks.

My models involved in the many to many are:

```
class Mage(models.Model):
    arcana = models.ManyToManyField('ArcanumAbility', through='CharacterArcanumLink', related_name='mage_by_arcana')

class ArcanumAbility(models.Model):

    class Arcana(AutoNumber):
        FATE = ()
        MIND = ()
        SPIRIT = ()
        DEATH = ()
        FORCES = ()
        TIME = ()
        SPACE = ()
        LIFE = ()
        MATTER = ()
        PRIME = ()

    arcanum = EnumField(Arcana)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Arcana Abilities"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.arcanum.label

class CharacterArcanumLink(Trait):
    PRIORITY_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Unassigned'), (1, 'Ruling'), (2, 'Common'), (3, 'Inferior')
    )
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES, default=0)
    mage = models.ForeignKey('Mage')
    arcana = models.ForeignKey('ArcanumAbility')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('mage', 'arcana')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.arcana.arcanum.label
```

<sub>Where the `Trait` mixin provides a `current_value`</sub>

To serialize the above relation into my JSON, I have tried these two patters on my serializer:

```
class CharacterArcanumLinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CharacterArcanumLink
        fields = ('current_value', 'arcana')

class MageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    arcana = CharacterArcanumLinkSerializer()
    ....
    class Meta:
        model = Mage
        fields = (...., 'arcana', ....)
        depth = 1
```

But that gives me this error:

```
AttributeError at /mages
'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'arcana'
```

Which is from (ultimately):

```
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py in get_attribute
        if instance is None:
            # Break out early if we get `None` at any point in a nested lookup.
            return None
        try:
            if isinstance(instance, collections.Mapping):
                instance = instance[attr]
            else:
                instance = getattr(instance, attr) ...
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None
        if is_simple_callable(instance):
            instance = instance()
    return instance
▼ Local vars
    Variable:   Value
    instance:   <django.db.models.fields.related.create_many_related_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x0000000004E4D4A8>
    attr:    'arcana'
    attrs:    ['arcana']
```

(Question: What trick to I need to go from my ManyRelatedManager to it's fields?)

And I've also tried not specifying a special serializer, and just having `'arcana'` in my fields, and pull it from my model. That leads to this error:

```
TypeError at /mages
<Arcana.FATE: 1> is not JSON serializable
```

Where the `1` is from the PK on the ArcanumAbility not the value on the through table. The issue here is that the Mage class has a M2M field that points to the `'ArcanumAbility'` model, so all that DRF tries to do is serialize the Enum on it.

So what method should I use if I want a JSON dictionary of all the relationships from Mage to ArcanumAbility with data from the through table?

Responding to [Mark R.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539340/access-different-fields-on-manyrelatedmanager-using-django-rest-framework#comment45392810_28539340), I'd like it looks like so:

```
....
"arcanum": {
           "Fate": 2,
           "Spirit": 0,
           "Mind": 3,
           ....
           }
```

Hopefully that's a clear enough sample.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you want the resulting JSON object to look like?

Comment: @MarkR. is that clearer? That's what I mean by a JSON Dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, that works; I'll try and replicate your issue locally shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed, if you add a related_name="linked_arcana" to the mage field in the CharacterArcanumLink class, you should be able to do something like this:

```python
class MageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    arcana = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_arcana(self, obj):
         if obj:
             return {str(x): x.current_value for x in obj.linked_arcana.all()}
```

Comment: C/P this in, and I get "`It is redundant to specify `get_arcana` on SerializerMethodField 'arcana' in serializer 'MageSerializer', because it is the same as the default method name. Remove the `method_name` argument.`" changing the method name to 'getarcana' and it just gives me a list of 'arcana' again, not a dictionary. It has inspired me to write myt own method very similar to my approach elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I was just throwing it out as a general approach; method-based serializers, especially for read-only serialization are usually much simpler than trying to wrangle DRF's built-in myriad of options.

Comment: Keep in mind that writing to M2M or even general FK relationships is pretty complex with vanilla DRF

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this working like so:

```
arcana = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_arcana(self, obj):
    if obj:
        return {str(link): link.current_value
                for link in CharacterArcanumLink.objects.filter(mage=obj)}
```

Heavily inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28540008/1075247) answer.

Comment: You can use the original method name ("get_arcana") by removing the parameter to the SerializerMethodField call entirely.

Comment: Doesn't obj.arcana.all() return all linked objects? So you could do, uh, {x.arcanum.label: x.arcanum.current_value for x in obj.arcana.all()} or something like that.

Comment: @MarkR. nope, I don't think it does. `obj.arcana.all()` gives `all()`  the `ArcanumAbilities` associated to the `Mage`. `ArcanumAbilities.all().arcanum.label` and `ArcanumAbilities.all().arcanum.current value` doesn't make sense, as there is not reverse relationship set up on that arm of the M2M relation. Is there?

Comment: Yeah, you'd still iterate over them but there wouldn't be a need to query each one separately since obj.arcana.all() == Mage.objects.get(pk=current_mage_id).arcana.all(), thus, you should be able to build a dict directly with that.

Comment: @MarkR. so how would I form that query? would you use a `select_related` type call?

Comment: @MarkR. I think I've figured it out. The dictionary comprehension I've used in the answer should only make one query.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was driving at -- since you already have all the info you need under .arcana.all(), you just need to dict-ify it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71016/discussion-between-pureferret-and-mark-r).